# Colors in ssh connection

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, colors

I have a colorful bash terminal (e.g. ls and vim show colors when configured to do so).

How can I have these colors when connecting to a remote server via ssh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [dircolors.sh](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/profile.html#etc-profile.d-dircolors.sh) subsection from "Beyond Linux From Scratch" book:

> This script uses the `~/.dircolors` and `/etc/dircolors` files to control
>   the colors of file names in a directory listing. They control
>   colorized output of things like **ls --color**. The explanation of how to
>   initialize these files is at the end of this section.
>
> ```
> cat > /etc/profile.d/dircolors.sh << "EOF"
> # Setup for /bin/ls and /bin/grep to support color, the alias is in /etc/bashrc.
> if [ -f "/etc/dircolors" ] ; then
>         eval $(dircolors -b /etc/dircolors)
>
>         if [ -f "$HOME/.dircolors" ] ; then
>                 eval $(dircolors -b $HOME/.dircolors)
>         fi
> fi
> alias ls='ls --color=auto'
> alias grep='grep --color=auto'
> EOF
> ```

Comment: Can you expand your answer a little? The question has 2,800 views — would be great to add a little more context.

Comment: Fedora 20 also comes with a [colorls.sh](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/coreutils-colorls.sh?h=f20) script.

Answer (score 4):

Using a combination of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9883/how-can-i-run-a-script-immediately-after-connecting-via-ssh and nik's answer you can do:

```
ssh host.example.com -t '. /etc/profile; . ~/.profile; /bin/bash'
```

This will execute your profile scripts on login, then open a bash shell. Your profile scripts are where the colors are defined.

Or, for maximum convenience, add the following to your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host *
  LocalCommand . /etc/profile; . ~/.profile; /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

I just edited `~/.bashrc` in the remote server to contain the following line:

```
alias ls='ls --color'
```